# Поиск слов из списка в строке Python

Tags: python, список

Есть список слов, вида:

```
animalslist=['кот', 'собака', 'олень', 'тюлень']
```

длинною в 600+ слов

Имеется строка, введённая пользователем, вида:

```
message='Какой либо текст олень какой либо текст'
```

Как эффективнее всего можно узнать, имеются ли в строке слова из списка

Длина строки заранее не известна

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if set(animalslist) & set(message.split()):
    print('В строке есть слова из списка')
```

Comment: Только надо текст предварительно очистить от точек, запятых и прочего.

Comment: @Эникейщик я не стал усложнять ответ, но да, идея хорошая: `message.lower().translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))`

Answer (score 1):

Должно немного быстрее (если время в вашем случаем можно принять за критерий эффективности) работать, когда так (крутой вариант от [vadim vaduxa](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/208915/vadim-vaduxa)):

```
animalslist = ['кот', 'собака', 'олень', 'тюлень']
message = 'Какой либо текст олень какой либо кот текст олень'.split()
sm = set(message)

print([f'{word} == {message.count(word)}' for word in animalslist if word in sm])
# ['кот == 1', 'олень == 2']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
animalslist = ['кот', 'собака', 'олень', 'тюлень']
message = 'Какой либо текст олень какой либо кот текст олень'.split()
sm = set(message)

# ['олень', 'кот']
print([a for a in sm if a in animalslist])

# ['кот=1', 'олень=2']
print([f'{a}={c}' for a, c in ([a, message.count(a)] for a in animalslist if a in sm) if c])
```

Comment: Квадратичный алгоритм.